# Can relay fragment arguments be composed different from argument definition?

Tags: relayjs, relay, react-relay

I have the following fragment definition

```
  fragment LocationFragment_viewer on Viewer
    @argumentDefinitions(userId: {type: "Int!"}) {
    results: locations(
      user_id: $userId
    ) {
      ...some_other_fragments
    }
  }
```

I want to change the argument from `user_id` to `user_ids` (which is just an array wrapping the id) in the GraphQL query, without changing the argument definition.

So I want something like:

```
  fragment LocationFragment_viewer on Viewer
    @argumentDefinitions(userId: {type: "Int!"}) {
    results: locations(
      user_ids: [$userId]
    ) {
      ...some_other_fragments
    }
  }
```

Is this even possible? In my case it is a bit hard to change the argument definitions, so trying to see if there is something easy to do without going that route.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found that Relay has added support for this in https://github.com/facebook/relay/releases/tag/v8.0.0

This means arguments can be composed like:

```
inputs: [{query: $my_query}, $other_input, null, $another_input]
```

Exactly what I need!